# Stream characteristics for the streams generated for SortedMap may not be SORTED if created with custom Comparator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Mastering Lambdas by Maurice Naftalin, Ch6 - Stream Performance.

There is explanation about the different characteristics of streams at the different stages of execution(intermediate & terminal).
For eg.

```
Stream.of(8,3,5,6,7,4)//ORDERED, SIZED
.filer(i->i%2==0) // ORDERED
.sorted() // ORDERED, SORTED
.distinct() // DISTINCT, ORDERED, SORTED
.map(i->i+1) // ORDERED
.unordered(); //none
```

What was confusing to me was explanation of SORTED characteristics :

**"Stream elements may have been sorted in other orders if a Comparator has been defined and used for the purpose, but such streams do not have the SORTED characteristic."**

Why if the custom comparator is provided for the implementation of Sorted Data Structure(SortedMap in above case) the framework would not consider creating streams with SORTED characteristic?

Comment: Did you just ask the same question twice?

Comment: No, title was mistakenly pasted as I thought it is two different question. I already edited the title.

Comment: I think they should've named it `NATURAL_SORTED` rather than `SORTED`. It is an implementation detail and nothing is mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flown is absolutely correct in his comment. `SORTED` is only reported for natural order and this has been debated before. First this is even internally used as a flag called: `isNaturalSort`:

```
/**
     * Sort using natural order of {@literal <T>} which must be
     * {@code Comparable}.
     */
    OfRef(AbstractPipeline<?, T, ?> upstream) {
        super(upstream, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
              StreamOpFlag.IS_ORDERED | StreamOpFlag.IS_SORTED);
        this.isNaturalSort = true;
```

The same flag `isNaturalSort` is set to `false` when used via `sorted(CustomComparator)`.

This is *an internal* details and it seems that the jdk developers did not find useful to implemented it as such - there was probably nothing to do with it that could be really useful. But this might change...

There is at least one flaw here still. Imagine a class like this:

```
static class User implements Comparable<User> {
    private final int id;

    public User(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User usr) {
        return 42; // don't do this
    }

}
```

And some stream operations:

```
Stream<User> byId = Stream.of(new User(12), new User(10))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getId));

System.out.println(byId.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));

Stream<User> natural = Stream.of(new User(12), new User(10))
            .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder());

System.out.println(natural.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)); 

Stream<User> plain = Stream.of(new User(12), new User(10)).sorted();
System.out.println(plain.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));
```

The first two report `false`, but the last one reports `true`; which is *at least* weird.

Comment: It is not technically "weird". It's simply not possible to detect whether the comparator is a `naturalOrder` one (at least, not without odd hacks). So it's at least ... unfortunate, because one might reasonably expect `sorted()` and `sorted(naturalOrder())` to yield the same result....

Comment: @Marco13: that’s actually simple: `comparator==Comparator.naturalOrder()`. While this is implementation specific, the Stream implementation is part of the same JRE having that `Comparator` implementation for which this test works…

Comment: @Holger That would be borderline to what I'd call a hack - mainly because it does not cover the case of a hand-crafted comparator that compares by natural order, let alone cases like `reverse(reverse(natural()))` ...

Comment: @Marco13: do you mean `Comparator.naturalOrder()==Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed().reversed()`? That will return `true` in OpenJDK/ Oracle’s JRE. Besides that, I do already know that “we can’t cover 100% of all cases, therefore, we decided to not support even the reasonable 99%” explanation. I’m still not convinced…

Comment: @Holger The `reverse` should be a placeholder for the [`reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator-) method. But it's true, all this won't compensate for the somewhat confusing naming of `SORTED` vs. something like `NATURALLY_SORTED`.

Comment: @Marco13: Keep in mind that `StreamOpFlag.IS_SORTED` is not `public` and hence, its inconsistent usage not confusing to those looking at the official API only. The `Spliterator` API allows reporting the `SORTED` characteristic for non-natural orders and has a [`getComparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#getComparator--) method allowing to get the actual order. This is what you get, e.g. from `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()).stream() .spliterator()`; it will report the `SORTED` characteristic together with the reverse order comparator.