# What is more efficient: sorted stream or sorting a list?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

Assume we have some items in a collection and we want to sort them using certain comparator, expecting result in a list:

```
Collection<Item> items = ...;
Comparator<Item> itemComparator = ...;
```

One of the approaches is to sort items in a list, something like:

```
List<Item> sortedItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
Collections.sort(sortedItems, itemComparator);
```

Anothe approach is using a sorted stream:

```
List<Item> sortedItems = items
    .stream()
    .sorted(itemComparator)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I wonder, which approach is more efficient? Are there any advantages of a sorted stream (like faste sorting on multiple cores)?

Efficient in a sense of runtime complexity/fastest.

I don't trust myself to implement a perfect [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) and studying `SortedOps` did not really enlighten me.

Comment: well at least one is sorting in place and there is no way to make it parallel (if you have enough data to squeeze some performance)

Comment: What do you mean by *efficient*? Fastest = `Collections.sort`; Most Readable = `Stream`; Most memory efficient = `Collections.sort` perhaps ...

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Fastest. I've added that to the question.

Comment: both use `Arrays#sort` as far as I see

Comment: @Eugene just checked again. My statement is only true for primitives. =) (that's the reason I deleted my comment)

Comment: @Aominè *almost* smart - it will only not do anything for a natural sort...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486170/stream-characteristics-for-the-streams-generated-for-sortedmap-may-not-be-sorted

Comment: interesting... why would you offer a bounty here? not that I mind, I don't really care, but wondering what the two answers have (plus yours) have not already answered

Comment: @Eugene As it is stated in the description of the bounty, I want to award it to one of the existing answers - yours. You put an effort to actually write a benchmark, I think it is worth additional bounty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is safe to say that two forms of sort will have the same complexity ... even without looking at the code.  (If they didn't then one form would be severely broken!)

Looking at Java 8 source code for streams (specifically the internal class `java.util.stream.SortedOps`), the `sorted()` method adds a component to a stream pipeline that captures all of the stream elements into either an array or an `ArrayList`.

- An array is used if and only if the pipeline assembly code can deduce the number of elements in the stream ahead of time.
- Otherwise, an `ArrayList` is used to gather the elements to be sorted.

If an `ArrayList` is used, you incur the extra overhead of building / growing the list.

Then we return to two versions of the code:

```
List<Item> sortedItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
Collections.sort(sortedItems, itemComparator);
```

In this version, the `ArrayList` constructor copies the elements `items` to an appropriately sized array, and then `Collections.sort` does an in-place sort of that array.  (This happens under the covers).

```
List<Item> sortedItems = items
    .stream()
    .sorted(itemComparator)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this version, as we have seen above, the code associated with `sorted()` either builds and sorts an array (equivalent to what happens above) or it builds the `ArrayList` the slow way.  But on top of that, there are the overheads of stream the data from `items` and to the collector.

Overall (with the Java 8 implementation at least) code examination tells me that first version of the code cannot be slower than the second version, and in most (if not all) cases it will be faster.   But as the list gets larger, the `O(NlogN)` sorting will tend to dominate the `O(N)` overheads of copying.  That will mean that the *relative* difference between the two versions will get smaller.

If you really care, you should write a benchmark to test the actual difference with a specific implementation of Java, and a specific input dataset.  (Or adapt @Eugene's benchmark!)

Comment: If an ArrayList is used then sortedItems.sort(itemComperator) should be used. There is a ArrayList specific implementation that is faster than the standard one.

Answer (score 18):

To be honest I don't trust myself *too much* either in `JMH` (unless I understand the assembly, which takes lots of time in my case), especially since I've used `@Setup(Level.Invocation)`, but here is a small test (I took the `StringInput` generation from some other test I did, but it should not matter, it's just some data to sort)

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class StringInput {

    private String[] letters = { "q", "a", "z", "w", "s", "x", "e", "d", "c", "r", "f", "v", "t", "g", "b",
            "y", "h", "n", "u", "j", "m", "i", "k", "o", "l", "p" };

    public String s = "";

    public List<String> list;

    @Param(value = { "1000", "10000", "100000" })
    int next;

    @TearDown(Level.Invocation)
    public void tearDown() {
        s = null;
    }

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void setUp() {

         list = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                .ints(next, 0, letters.length)
                .mapToObj(x -> letters[x])
                .map(x -> Character.toString((char) x.intValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}


@Fork(1)
@Benchmark
public List<String> testCollection(StringInput si){
    Collections.sort(si.list, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    return si.list;
}

@Fork(1)
@Benchmark
public List<String> testStream(StringInput si){
    return si.list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Results show that `Collections.sort` is faster, but not by a big margin:

```
Benchmark                                 (next)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
streamvsLoop.StreamVsLoop.testCollection    1000  avgt    2   0.038          ms/op
streamvsLoop.StreamVsLoop.testCollection   10000  avgt    2   0.599          ms/op
streamvsLoop.StreamVsLoop.testCollection  100000  avgt    2  12.488          ms/op
streamvsLoop.StreamVsLoop.testStream        1000  avgt    2   0.048          ms/op
streamvsLoop.StreamVsLoop.testStream       10000  avgt    2   0.808          ms/op
streamvsLoop.StreamVsLoop.testStream      100000  avgt    2  15.652          ms/op
```

Comment: I've also started writing a benchmark, we'll see what I get.

Comment: *"So stream is a little bit slower."* - As predicted :-)

Comment: I’m a bit surprised about the baroque way of creating the list, concatenating strings just to split them afterwards. How about `int[] letters = IntStream.range('A', 'Z').toArray(); List<String> random = IntStream.range(0, listSize) .mapToObj(ix -> ThreadLocalRandom.current() .ints(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, maxWordSize), 0, letters.length) .map(i -> letters[i]) .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString()) .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`?

Comment: @Holger no no, you are correct, its morw than ugly, I had 20 minutes between two meetings, had to build the JMH test amd run it, so I took it from a test I already had in place. Very nice what you have done btw :)

Comment: @Holger while this is indeed much nicer, it does not fit the JMH rules of testing (at least not something I would like). What I would like to create is the *same* input for each iteration of the tests. so `test1` must get `abcd` and `test2` would still get `abcd`...

Comment: How does your code ensure that each iteration gets the same list?

Comment: @Holger for the test where I got this input from, what I needed is the same sizes of Strings

Comment: Well, it’s so hard to recognize what your code actually does. When you want a fixed word size, just replace `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, maxWordSize)` with `desiredWordSize` in my code and you’re done… But this has nothing to do with the JMH rules, as your code still generates a new list each time just like mine.

Comment: @Holger didn't see the edit. it should generate a new List, actually it does so every time because of `Level.Invocation`. I don't get your point here. Let's suppose I want to test "something" that deals with Strings and their lengths, well if I have two tests to benchmark - I want them both to get the same input for each trial, and by "same" I really mean of same lengths. Since `@Setup` is invoked for each trial - if I used any kind of "random", I might get different lengths for `testA` and `testB`

Comment: @Holger thus I've used `@Param` here, and I know that for each trial when `param == 1000` for example, I would generate inputs for the benchmark that would fit into "the same" pattern. I've been through the JMH documentation and samples a few times - even pinged Shipilev on this a few times, on how to actually do that in a *JMH-ish* way, because right now I don't like it either too much

Comment: @Eugene my point was, my suggested alternative is not less “JMH-ish” than yours, just much simpler. Since your code is so complicated, I didn’t recognize that it generates words of the same size and provided a solution generating words of random size. But as shown in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798129/what-is-more-efficient-sorted-stream-or-sorting-a-list#comment86637823_49799144), it’s easy to make it fixed word sized; it’s even simpler. You could even make the desired word size a parameter.

Comment: @Holger agreed. I looked at it again and you make perfect sense, I only used a smaller version of your proposal here though. thank you

Comment: You seem to really like that `Character.toString(…)` method, don’t you? Now, you’re even trying to invoke it on a `String` (your `letters` array still is that pre-shuffled array of strings). In the end, your shortened version would create single-character words only, if it worked.

Comment: @Holger taking into consideration that I thought of single letter words only indeed, why is `Character#toString` so bad here? :|

Comment: You already have a single letter string. You are trying to invoke `intValue()` on it (which doesn’t compile), just to invoke `Character.toString` on it. I thought, I saw this already somewhere else, but maybe I’m wrong. Anyway, `.mapToObj(x -> letters[x])` produces a `String`, as `letters` has the type `String[]`. The entire subsequent `map` step is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my benchmark (not really sure if it is correct):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OperationsPerInvocation;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;

@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(MyBenchmark.N)
public class MyBenchmark {

    public static final int N = 50;

    public static final int SIZE = 100000;

    static List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        System.out.println("Generating the list");
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            sourceList.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Shuffling the list.");
        Collections.shuffle(sourceList);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> sortingList() {
        List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(sourceList);
        Collections.sort(sortedList);
        return sortedList;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> sortedStream() {
        List<Integer> sortedList = sourceList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return sortedList;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> treeSet() {
        Set<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(sourceList);
        List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(sortedSet);
        return sortedList;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt       Score       Error  Units
MyBenchmark.sortedStream  avgt  200  300691.436 ± 15894.717  ns/op
MyBenchmark.sortingList   avgt  200  262704.939 ±  5073.915  ns/op
MyBenchmark.treeSet       avgt  200  856577.553 ± 49296.565  ns/op
```

As in @Eugene's benchmark, sorting list is slightly (ca. 20%) faster than sorted stream. What surprizes me a bit is that `treeSet` is significantly slower. I did not expect that.

Comment: In a comment on a completely unrelated question/answer, Holger has once explained me why `TreeSet` is slower: Adding to a `TreeSet` is [O(log n)](http://infotechgems.blogspot.nl/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html), and unless the `sourceList` is sorted by the same comparator, `addAll` will simply call `add` for each element. In plain terms, the slower performance stems from the fact that `TreeSet` keeps itself sorted at all times. This results in way more comparisons when adding many elements, as opposed to adding all elements first and then sorting like you do in `sortingList`.

Comment: @MalteHartwig nice! just looked up the sources for it. thank you

Comment: @MalteHartwig well, sorting the list also has a worst case of O(n×log n), but in practice, it’s between O(n) and that worst case. But keep in mind that inserting into a tree map also implies allocating a node object and potentially rebalancing the tree. In contrast, `new ArrayList<>(collection)` just allocates and populates one array.

Comment: @lexicore there are a few problems as far as I see here, the only way to do this correctly is to go to the JMH samples (*numerous and numerous* times.. ), simple tests are simple to do, well a bit more complicated and it gets fun! that being said here are the thing I don't like personally: 1) One of your tests does this `List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(sourceList);` - implies that this is now part of the benchmark itself (Setup methods classes are for this) 2) you are shuffling your collection *once* - after that it is the same for all threads/tests

Comment: @lexicore (continued) /trials; this might trigger optimizations that you are no aware of. correct way to do it would be to generate something pseudo-random for... well the next word is not easy to choose. *In your example* it should really be `Invocation`, since you are sorting, and IIRC sorting an already sorted list is much faster then one that is not (JMH even has an example about this with bubble sort). So data should be provided to each trial already shuffled and out of order (read my last two comments at my answer)

Comment: @lexicore 3) then read about `@Fork` 4) `@OperationsPerInvocation` is dangerous, like any other JMH annotation that you don't really understand - the samples are there to help! 5) The most painful one : JMH is not going to tell you what you did wrong - you are going to measure "something", whatever that makes sense or not is an entire different story

Comment: @Eugene This is the first benchmark I ever did with JMH, so I'm not suprprized I did not do it right. This was one of the reasons I actually did not want to do it myself.

Comment: @lexicore understood, boy you will have fun :) go through the examples - its an entire new world there!

Comment: @Eugene I actually cargo-culted this from some example I've found somewhere.

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for your feedback. The only think I don't quite agree is 1). I think `new ArrayList<>(sourceList);` should be part of the benchmark, as creating the resulting list is a part of every version. I test creation of a sorted copy of the given list.

Comment: @lexicore may be - this depends on what you really want to test - **just** the sorting?

Comment: @Eugene I want to test sorted stream vs. sorting list. But in case of a stream I have to collect items in a list to get a result. This basically creates a sorted copy of the original list. So to make it fair, I have to create a copy of the original list for in-place sorting as well.

Comment: @lexicore makes sense, yes. But in case of the stream there is no way to specify the initial capacity, so lots of resizes pottentially, they could steal the time you see in output... If I make sense

Comment: @Eugene Sure, I get it. My interest is actually quite practical. I saw a lot of usages of a sorted stream to sort something in answers recently. I was sceptical that it's better that creating a copy and `Collections.sort`ing that copy.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old one. In my particular case, I wanted to keep the list once sorted, so I choose to sort the list directly as it seemed counter intuitive to pass the list to a stream to then being forced to collect the result and re-asign it. In other parts where I actually wanted to preserve original state, then the stream became the best option.
I hope it helps...
Here are my 2 examples:

```
class Student {
  private List<ClassSubject> classes;

  public void sortClassesByTime() {
     // imagine by definition a scheudle will use classes ordered by time
     classes.sort(Comparator.comparing(ClassSubject::getTime));
     // List classes will be forever sorted by time
  }

   public void /* List<ClassSubject> */ sortClassesByGrade() {
      // Imagine schedules are fixed once assigned, however grade changes with time, therefore it is OK to have a temporary ordering
      List<ClassSubject> sortedClasses = classes.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ClassSubject::getGrade).reversed())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
      classes = sortedClasses;
      // I think ideally here we would prefer to return the new list {sortedClasses} 
      // instead of overriding the original, but I wanted to ilustrate 
      // the example by getting the same rusults (just different sorting criteria)
   }
}
```

Comment: This not apropos to the question.  The question is actually about the performance of the two approaches ... not which is more "natural" or "intuitive".