# Is there any advantage to use stream().sorted() over Collection.sort()?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-stream

I used to use the following line to sort elements before streams showed up in Java:

```
Collections.sort(collection, new CustomComparator());
```

Now I found out that I can get the same result by doing:

```
collection.stream().sorted(new CustomComparator());
```

In both cases I use a list and a custom comparator that implements `Comparator` (I need this and cannot implement it on the class itself).

I haven't found anything that indicates that they are different in any way, except for the fact that the stream solution *looks nicer*.

Is there any advantage to use the stream version? I mean... is it more performant? Is there any difference?

Comment: `Collections.sort(...)` sorts a collection in place, while `collection.stream().sorted()` returns a sorted stream that you need to collect into a new variable (collection).

Comment: Thanks @Oleksandr. Great answer. I was about to make a mistake.

Comment: What about `collection.sort(new CustomComparator())`?

Comment: Performance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798129/what-is-more-efficient-sorted-stream-or-sorting-a-list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`collection.stream().sorted(new CustomComparator())` doesn't sort the `collection`, only makes the stream sorted.

To achieve a similar result with Stream API, you should use a terminal operation - collect into a new list:

```
collection.stream().sorted(new CustomComparator()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It won't modify the original collection (the stream source), but `Collections.sort` will.

---

I would make a copy of the collection and do sorting on it, in case the original order matters.

```
List<?> collectionCopy = new ArrayList(collection);
Collections.sort(collectionCopy, new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: So the advantage is just when you want to create a copy?