# Stream.sorted() then collect, or collect then List.sort()?

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-stream, collectors

In general, is there a performance difference between these two pieces of code?

```
List<Integer> list1 = someStream1.sorted().collect(toList());
// vs.
List<Integer> list2 = someStream2.collect(toList());
list2.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

Variant 2 is obviously yucky and should be avoided, but I'm curious if there are any performance optimizations built into the mainstream (heh, main*stream*) implementations of Stream that would result in a performance difference between these two.

I imagine that because the stream has strictly more information about the situation, it would have a better opportunity to optimize. E.g. I imagine if this had a `findFirst()` call tacked on, it would elide the sort, in favor of a `min` operation.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Ah yes, it's good to focus the question. I changed it to `Integer`, so the implementation of Comparable is known. I also changed the stream names, to make it clear i'm not iterating the same stream twice (which is invalid)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Or just `list.sort(null)`.

Comment: @shmosel that's interesting, thanks...never noticed that this was valid as well..thought that would throw a `NullPointerException` :)

Comment: IMHO, the answer by Stephen really makes more sense to understand the difference [What is more efficient: sorted stream or sorting a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798129/what-is-more-efficient-sorted-stream-or-sorting-a-list). Also, since the benchmarks are also there in the linked question, I would vote to mark this as a duplicate. (which i am pretty sure not many people would second :D )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both options should result in the same final result. But runtime characteristics **could** be different. What if the initial stream is a **parallel** one? Then option 1 would do a sort in parallel, whereas option 2 wouldn't do a "sequential" sort. The result should be the same, but the overall runtime resp. CPU load could be very much different then.

I would definitely prefer option 1 over 2: why create a list first, to then *later* sort it?!

Imagine for example you later want to collect into an *immutable* list. Then all code that follows your second pattern would break. Whereas code written using pattern 1 wouldn't be affected at all!

Of course, in the example here that shouldn't lead to issues, but what if the sort() happens in a slightly different place?!

Comment: If the stream can support sorting and collecting into an immutable list, does that mean that the stream has its own scratch buffer where it does the sorting, and then has to do a copy?

Comment: @Alexander correct, the current Stream implementation always use an internal buffer for sorting, which implies that the second variant will be slightly faster if you ensure that the result list is mutable and has in-place sorting support. Since `Collectors.toList()` guarantees neither, you have to use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead. But this precludes benefiting from potential future improvements made to `Collectors.toList()`. And you should not overestimate the copying costs. Before Java 8, `Collections.sort` always did *two* copying operations and almost nobody noticed…

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, streams are usually looked at as "transient" data that's being processed/manipulated, and collecting the stream conveys the notion you're done manipulating it.

While the second snippet should work, the first one would be the more idiomatic way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case the sorting happens in the call to `collect`. If the stream is already sorted this will be a no-op (the data will just pass through as-is). Might not make a big difference, but calling `Collections.sort` on an already sorted collection is  still O(n).

Also the first case benefits from parallel execution, as at least [OpenJDK](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/SortedOps.java) uses `Arrays.parallelSort`.

Apart from that the first line is cleaner, better to understand and less error prone when refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation, it seems that the first sort is not a stable sort implementation for the unordered streams:

> For ordered streams, the sort is stable. For unordered streams, no stability guarantees are made.

but the second one is a stable sort implementation:

> This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons.

So, the stability of the sort algorithm is one of the differences between these two lists sort methods.

Comment: I think your'e mixing up the first and second snippets. Either way, the end result is the same. If the stream is unordered, the resulting list will be unordered in the second case, so it won't help that the sort is stable.

Comment: Sort instability doesn't mean that the result won't necessarily be sorted. It just means that two objects which are equal may be reordered with respect to each other. For example, if the input is `[John Smith, Jane Smith, Joe Brown]` and we sort based on last name only, an unstable sort could produce `[Joe Brown, Jane Smith, John Smith]`.

Comment: thanks for all your comments, my friends. I have applied some changes to my answer according to your mentioned points.

Answer (score 1):

The list you get back from `Collectors.toList()` is not guaranteed to be editable. It *might* be an ArrayList, or an ImmutableList, you cannot know. Therefore you must not try to modify that list.

Comment: Good point, but a technicality. You can do `toCollection(ArrayList::new)` to get a mutable list.