# Does Java stream().sorted or list.sort() not increases time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, java-stream, time-complexity

While making some sortings, some people suggest using `stream().sorted` or `list.sort()` methods in Java to reduce time complexity. However, I think these methods also use some sorting algorithms that has a similar time complexity.

```
List result = list.stream().sorted((o1, o2)->o1.getItem().getValue().
                                   compareTo(o2.getItem().getValue())).
                                   collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, does it mean that these algorithms use the most efficient sorting algorithms for sorting less time than I sort in 2 nested for loop?

Comment: Time complexity is an abstract concept that doesn't necessarily map to runtime performance, what matters is the actual performance. But even if it weren't more efficient (it most certainly is if you have to ask this question since it's written by some of the best Java programmers and been investigated by many over the years) it's also extra code you don't have to maintain which is always a win.

Comment: When speaking about "2 nested for loop", I guess you are talking about bubble or insertion sort (or similar). These sort algorithms have time complexity O(n^2), whereas most other sorting algorithms - like merge sort e.g. - have time complexity O(n log n). So - yes - it is better to use Java's built-in sort algorithms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful comments and answers. Then I think I should use `stream().sorted` or `list.sort()` for lower time complexity even if they also generate a time complexity due to sorting. Is that true?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Chico, thanks for reply, but I know algorithms. Just needed to ask what if I use java-stream to sort my list in my method? As far as I see, it will also increase time complexity, but as less as possible as stream uses one of most suitable sorting algorithms. Anyhow, I voted up for your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of these methods is `O(nlog(n))`. And it's the best time complexity for sorting an array.

Comment: Well ... there are sorting algorithms that can sort in linear time - O(n). But they require more information. Time complexity O(n log n) is the best time complexity we can achieve _in the general case_.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose OK, but *these* methods asked about in the question are O(n log n), which is what this answer states. You're talking about algorithms which solve different, more constrained sorting problems.

Comment: I was commenting your statement "it's the best time complexity for sorting an array" which is not true because of the reasons I explained.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful comments and answers. Then I think I should use `stream().sorted` or `list.sort()` for lower time complexity even if they also generate a time complexity due to sorting. Is that true?

Comment: @harry `list.sort()` is a little better. For more information check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798129/what-is-more-efficient-sorted-stream-or-sorting-a-list).

Comment: The O(n) sorts like radix and bucket sorts (which the stream primitives do _not_ use) are actually Omega(nk), where k is the key length.  O(n log n) on a sort normally characterizes _number of comparisons_.  Only with certain kinds of machine models - which may or may not coincide with real machines -  is this the same as O(n log n) time. Comparisons of keys of length k can do better than omega(k). So  the "linear time" sorts can be inferior to comparison sorts if keys are long. As some have said, if the sort is a bottleneck, you need to test with realistic data to see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting algorithms that use nested loops are usually `O(n²)` complexity, due to every iteration of the inner loop occurring for every iteration of the outer loop. Some of these algorithms would be

- Insertion Sort;
- Bubble Sort;
- etc;

However, other do not use nested loops as you mentioned, for example, the most used sorting algorithm for general use would be QuickSort, which stands as a Divide and Conquer Algorithm, it starts by selecting a pivot value and rearranging the array based on said pivot value, with all smaller values coming before it, and all larger values coming after it (Not necessarily ordered yet).

QuickSort stands as `O(nlog(n))` Average case complexity. Do bear in mind that some of the more advanced sorting algorithms also have a worst case scenario complexity of `O(n^2)`.

In fact, some sorting implementations actually shuffle the array before sorting it just to avoid the worst case scenario.

I leave here some information about Quicksort below.

[Quicksort explanation and how it works](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful comments and answers. Then I think I should use `stream().sorted` or `list.sort()` for lower time complexity even if they also generate a time complexity due to sorting. Is that true?

Comment: Think of sorting your input as an investment. Finding the smallest value in an array is an `O(1)` operation if the array is sorted, but an `O(n)` if it isn't. This is true for more complex computations. It depends on whether you think you are going to compute a lot of times over the array or if the information streamlines your code, making it easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

**The very first impotent thing** that you have to understand about any kind of algorithm is that **just talking** about algorithms **will not significantly change your knowledge** in this area.

You have to `study and practice them`, implementing algorithms step by step.

If want to improve your understanding of sorting algorithms you need to start with the very basic like **`bubble sort`** and **`insertion sort`** (descriptions and pseudocode could've found in **`Wikipedia`** is quite enough to grasp the idea and start coding). When you'll have a firm understanding of the basics that you ready to go with **`merge sort`** and [**quicksort**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

[**Here is a small insight**](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2018-January/051000.html) on what is happening inside the so-called **dual-pivot quicksort** provided by JDK.

In fact, it's a very **`advanced compound algorithm`** which apart from the conventional quicksort entails `merge sort`, `heap sort`, and `parallel computing` in case of a massive data set.

Only when you know all `proc and cons` of the essential algorithms (like why there are different portition schemes out there, why quicksort is preferred over merge sort meanwhile in the worse case time complexity of the merge sort seems better, etc) it make sense to speculate about the `optimizations` that are going the **dual-pivot quicksort**.

For now short answer with regards to the performance of the build-in quicksort:

> **guarantees n*log(n) on any data**

**`Now about Streams and sorting.`**

Sorting is always happening `inside the array` in place. If the source of data is backed by the array an `ArrayList` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, then its underlying array will get sorted.

Otherwise, for instance, if you are dialing with a `LinkedList`, a new array will be allocated in memory and all the data from the list will be copied to this array and then get sorted.

And when you are dialing with a `stream` it'll `not affect the source` of data. The whole data from the source requires to be loaded into memory to be sorted. And then you most likely will store it in a brand collection.

**Conclusion:**

- if you need to change a source of data - use the `sort()` method with the list directly;
- if your task doesn't require sorting all the initial data (or you simply want to preserve the initial state of the source) - then `Stream API` will give a hand with filtering and sorting.